# Не срабатывает самодельный Button и как всё вынести в style?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, style, usercontrol

Почему мой button срабатывает только при нажатии либо на текст внутри, либо на картинку?

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="FlatButton">

........

<Button Template="{StaticResource FlatButton}" Margin="0,0,0,448" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0">

                    <Image Source="icon/add-new-document.png" Width="30" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Создать новый документ" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="16,0,0,0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF002354" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>    
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

И ещё, можно ли всё это запихнуть в style, чтобы на каждый button одно и тоже не писать?

UPD 1

Не никак :( не хочет устанавливаться ...

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="FlatButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <ContentPresenter/>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

UPD 2

```
<Button Template="{StaticResource FlatButton}" Margin="0,0,0,448" BorderThickness="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0" Background="Transparent">
                    <Image Source="icon/add-new-document.png" Width="30" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Создать новый документ" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="16,0,0,0" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <StackPanel.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF002354" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Style>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте у `StackPanel` выставить `Background="Transparent"`.

Comment: А Template вполне можно запихнуть в стиль.

Comment: @VladD если я поставлю Background,  то не будет срабатывать trigger :(

Comment: Окей, понял. Тогда установите фон тоже в стиле: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>`. Триггер-то срабатывает, просто установленный непосредственно фон сильнее, чем фон из стиля.

Comment: @VladD всмысле? Фон то должен быть с цветом #FF002354

Comment: А вы попробовали?

Comment: @VladD вы имеете ввиду `<Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>` запихнуть в  `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="FlatButton">` ?

Comment: @VladD тему обновил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: У меня нет в доступности Visual Studio, я не могу точно проверить. Насколько я помню, нужно следующее: 1) из Button убрать `Background="{x:Null}"` 2) Setter положить в стиль, перед `<Style.Triggers>`.

Comment: @VladD ну я вот в общем сделал как вы сказали, всё хорошо, но перестал срабатывать trigger и нету затемнения, ну то есть не затемнения а у меня там просто цвет на тон темнее (#FF002354), так вот у меня не меняется background, я вообще даже не знаю что придумать можно :( Тему обновил

Comment: А покажите тот код, при котором не работал триггер? У вас точно нигде нету прямой установки фона? Должна быть только в двух местах: в сеттере нормальный фон, и в триггере фон для mouseover.

Comment: @VladD ну вот в UPD 2 событие `Click` срабатывает для исполнения нужных действий уже в code-side, но затемнение trigger для затемнения так и не хочет работать. Пыхчу уже сутки над какой-то кнопочкой )

Comment: Ну я ж говорил, устанавливать Background для StackPanel нужно не непосредственно, как у вас, а из стиля. Добавьте setter перед Style.Triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче то что я хотел то и сделал, не обошлось без костылей. Вот рабочий код :

```
            <Button Template="{StaticResource FlatButton}" BorderThickness="1" Click="Button_Click_1" Height="61" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" >
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Создать документ" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,22,25,23" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    <Image Source="icon/add-new-document.png" Width="30" Margin="24,15,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Rectangle Fill="#00000000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="61" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="196"/>
                    <Grid.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Grid">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF23FF" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Style>
                </Grid>
            </Button>
```